# Remote control a KDE session?

Tags: kubuntu, android, remote-desktop

I've installed KDE Connect on my Android phone, and it appears to be a default install in Kubuntu 20.04 (which runs on my desktop computer) -- but this appears to mainly be useful for transferring files between the phone and computer and using the phone screen as a touchpad pointing device for the computer.

Is there a method to use an Android phone (original Pixel, Android 10, as updated as that model can get, if it matters) to log into and remotely control KDE Plasma Desktop sessions?  I have software on the Kubuntu machine that I'd like to be able to use from the phone -- and *preferably when I'm not at home* on the same wifi/LAN, though even on the LAN would be an improvement.

I see this as requiring something akin to the Windows Remote Desktop utility, along with an Android app that can act as a remote keyboard, display, and pointing device.  I'm okay with it requiring logging into a separate session from the default one that's left open on the Kubuntu machine, though ideally I'd want that user to  be able to access the same `/home` folder with its `~/desktop` etc.

Comment: A Google search shows what KDE connect can do. https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect#:~:text=KDE%20Connect%20is%20a%20project,your%20desktop%20from%20your%20phone It does not allow remote control of all the apps on the computer.

Comment: @David That's why I'm looking for something else.  For remote desktop operation.

Comment: Are you familiar with VNC? RealVNC is free for personal use. https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/ Install VNC Server on your computer, and VNC Viewer on your phone (from the phone's app store).

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Not FOSS, I see.  Worth considering, but for this situation, a monthly subscription probably isn't the right model.

Comment: It is free for personal use. No monthly subscription required.

Comment: That sounds like an answer, then @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: I will write the answer later on today. Meanwhile, you can try out the app.